# processing multiple files with awk problem

Tags: awk, gawk

I've the input files with fields separated with colon:

main:

```
one:111:222:333
fiv:333:222:333
two:123:234:500
```

file1:

```
one:111:222:333
two:123:234:501
```

file2:

```
one:111:222:333
thr:-:234:232
fiv:999:500:232
```

Thanks to hints on [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433302) I have a bit modified awk code:

```
$ awk -F':' -vf=main 'FILENAME==f{m=$0};FILENAME!=f&&$2~/[0-9]+/{if ($2~/[0-9]+/&&(!($1 in a) || $3 > a[$1])) { a[$1] = $3; b[$1] = $0 } next;}{if (($1 in a) && (a[$1] > $3)){ print b[$1]":updated:"m; delete b[$1] } else print; }' file* main
thr:-:234:232
one:111:222:333
fiv:999:500:232:updated:fiv:333:222:333
two:123:234:500
```

Why it prints also line `thr:-:234:232`? 
As `thr` does not occur in main file, it should be ignored for any update in it. 
Updated should be only these lines basing on 1st column, which exists in main file and corresponding lines with 1st column exist in file1 or file2 and have bigger value in 3rd column.

Why `$2~/[0-9]+/` does not work here?

Update:
It still did not figured it out, please have a look:

when I modify test main file to:

`one:111:222:333
fiv:333:222:333
two:123:234:500
ten.233:422:452`

And run this awk command:

```
$ awk -F':' -vf=main 'FILENAME==f{m=$0};FILENAME!=f&&$2~/[0-9]+/{if ($2~/[0-9]+/&&(!($1 in a) || $3 > a[$1])) { a[$1] = $3; b[$1] = $0 } next;}{if (($1 in a) && (a[$1] > $3)){ print b[$1]":updated:"m; delete b[$1] } else print; }' file* main
thr:-:234:232
one:111:222:333
fiv:999:500:232:updated:fiv:333:222:333
two:123:234:500
ten.233:422:452
```

So output is wrong because of thr line which should not be on output as `thr` is not in `main` file

I modified command adding additional condition `else if($1 in a) {print};`
but then it does not print line beginning with "ten" in main file:

```
$ awk -F':' -vf=main 'FILENAME==f{m=$0};FILENAME!=f&&$2~/[0-9]+/{if ($2~/[0-9]+/&&(!($1 in a) || $3 > a[$1])) { a[$1] = $3; b[$1] = $0 } next;}{if (($1 in a) && (a[$1] > $3)){ print b[$1]":updated:"m; delete b[$1] } else if($1 in a) {print}; }' file* main
one:111:222:333
fiv:999:500:232:updated:fiv:333:222:333
two:123:234:500
```

I'll appreciate any help very much.

Awk is really very awesome, unfortunately I being not a programmer can't figure it out on my own yet.

Comment: That is a gnarly one-liner. Whitespace is free you know

Answer (score 3):

Because you have `next` in the block with condition `FILENAME != f && $2 ~ /[0-9]+/`. That `thr` line does not meet that condition, so it falls into the "every line" block. There, $1 is not in `a` so the `else` block is entered and the line is printed.

I'm sure you would have been able to figure this out yourself if you just used sensible indentation so you actually see your program:

```
awk -F':' -vf=main '
    FILENAME == f {m = $0}
    FILENAME != f && $2 ~ /[0-9]+/ {
        if ($2 ~ /[0-9]+/ && (!($1 in a) || $3 > a[$1])) { 
            a[$1] = $3
            b[$1] = $0 
        } 
        next
    }
    {
        if (($1 in a) && (a[$1] > $3)) { 
            print b[$1]":updated:"m
            delete b[$1] 
        } else 
            print
    }
' file* main
```

Comment: I am not sure how to add the condition to ignore such line, so ignore lines of file{1,2} having $1 value which is not occuring in main's $1

Comment: probably I have figured it out, I additional if at the end ```else if ($1 in a){ print }; }'``` I am not a programmer, usually works only with HW and some bash scripting, I will appreciate someone explain the ```a``` in the code which is black magic for me, it represents main files entries or any file? where/when it was "established"?